# Why is in my expect function a single Quote?

Tags: postman

If i use a environment variable in my expect function Postman tries to compare my Variable with a ' which is not a part of my variable.

```
let Id = pm.environment.get("KundenId");
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () { pm.response.to.have.status(200); });

pm.test("Is ID equal", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.equal(Id);
});

pm.test("Response time is less than 50ms", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(250);
});
postman.setNextRequest(null);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you please edit and make it more clear?

Comment: Is the response `id` a number? If so, you might need to do `parseInt(pm.environment.get(var_name))` as everything in the environment file is a `string`